# SQL Filtering To Show Rows Only That Have Value in One Column Appear Multiple Times

Tags: sql

Pretend I have a dataset that looks like the following

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5
1   NA  NA  NA      34
2   NA  NA  NA      39
3   NA  NA  NA      29
4   NA  NA  NA      17
5   NA  NA  NA      17
6   NA  NA  NA      34
```

If I want to return only the rows where in C5 there exist duplicates, how do I do this? So I would want rows 1 and 6, as well as 4 and 5.

Comment: Which database you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.c5 = t.ct and t2.c1 <> t.c1);
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c5) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: If table t is a result of a few table joins, how do I incorporate this logic? Seems like SQL doesnt like the where exist clause when I have joins mixed in

Comment: @j_nj . . . You can define `t` using a CTE with either query.  Or just use the second version.

Comment: ive never used a CTE, would you be able to help explain that? Also my current version of mysql cant run windows functions and I'm unable to upgrade for the time being so that is unfortunately out of the realm of possibility for now

Comment: `with t as (<your query here>) select . . .`